# Oracle table partitioning options

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have a transactions table in oracle db with up to 20 million records/day across multiple accounts, with accounts growing to ~100.

In order to make my queries as fast as possible, I was considering:

1. A range partition on date field over 1 day interval
2. A hash partition on account number field, so each account has it own set daily set of transactions

I guess oracle will treat the the table as a logical table, and create a physical table per partition?

Any recommendations on the 2 different partitions (range and hash)? And any special considerations on purging data in a partitioned table.

Thanks

Comment: Post you representative queries to be able to hint. E.g. if you often filter a *range* - the *hash* partitioning will not help.

Comment: Why hash partition on account number? Maybe range on account number would be also working.

Comment: Often partitioning does not speed up your queries, don't expect any miracles. The queries may go faster if the partitioning design is very well coordinated with your  queries. However, when you have to purge old data then DROP/TRUNCATE partition is much faster than DELETE.

Answer (score 0):

> I guess oracle will treat the the table as a logical table, and create a physical table per partition?

Physical segment per partition(or subpartition in case of subpartitioning)

> Any recommendations on the 2 different partitions (range and hash)? And any special considerations on purging data in a partitioned table.

It's difficult to suggest anything without knowing your data and data processing, but you can also consider a [composite partitioning](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-BE424ACC-F746-4CA8-973C-F578CF98FF10.htm#VLDBG00225): range partitioning by date and hash subpartitioning by account. In case of partitioning by date you can drop partitions by date (`ALTER TABLE ... DROP PARTITION FOR(...)`)